# Show Sql table record in Gridview

Tags: c#, sql-server

In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3A6F.png) table I enter multiple records from gridview dynamic rows.

Now I want to show [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1n0N.png) records on a different page gridview like this. Please suggest me what I should put in my SQL query. I am using C# SQL Server.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Your Picture

[image]

```
--Test Data
CREATE TABLE YourTable
    ([col] int, [col2] int, [col3] int, [col4] varchar(13), [col5] varchar(6), [col6] varchar(6), [col7] varchar(10), [col8] varchar(7), [col9] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO YourTable
    ([col], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7], [col8], [col9])
VALUES
    (4, 4, 4, 'Home Threatre', 'Area', 'Deepak', 'Gram', 'CCAA2', 'Inches'),
    (5, 5, 4, 'Home Threatre', 'Area', 'Rahul', 'Inches', NULL, '0'),
    (6, 6, 5, 'Home Threatre', 'length', 'a1', 'Gram', 'ann2', 'IClogram'),
    (7, 7, 5, 'Home Threatre', 'length', 'bl', 'Centimeter', 'bnn2', 'Meter'),
    (8, 8, 6, 'Home Threatre', 'Width', 'zzl', 'Centimeter', 'z222', 'Centimeter'),
    (9, 9, 6, 'Home Threatre', 'Width', ')71', 'Milimeter', 'y222', 'Milimeter'),
    (10, 10, 6, 'Home Threatre', 'Width', 'x211', 'Centimeter', NULL, '0'),
    (11, 11, 3, '2PinSwitch', 'A3pin3', 'sddsf', 'Meter', 'dsfsctf', 'Milimeter'),
    (12, 12, 3, '2PinSwitch', 'A3pin3', 'dddd', 'Centimeter', NULL, '0')
;

--Query Script
select [col], [col2], [col3], [col4], 
  case when rank = 1 then
    [col5]
  else
    ''
  end as [col5]
  , [col6], [col7], [col8], [col9]
from (
  select 
    *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col5 ORDER BY col5 ASC) rank
  from YourTable
) TempTable
```

### Result :

[image]

---

[DEMO LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bacc3/6/0)

Comment: thanku so much . its working for me

Comment: @deepak singh If it worked for you, then accept his answer please.

Comment: @Nashmár  thanks  :)